# Add DateFormatProvider in Java EE environment or dynamically

Tags: java, localization

I need for some custom locales special `DateFormatProviders`. Can I add a `DateFormatProvider`-implementation without adding an `extension-jar` into the `java.ext.dirs-path` or at runtime?

We are using `Oracle Weblogic 10.3.x` and deploy our application as ear.
Does Java EE or Weblogic provide a mechanism for this purpose?